# Xamarin.Android .apk not binding?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I wrote simple application in Xamarin.Android using MvvmCross. There are two activities: LoginActivity and HomeActivity.

At the begining I am showing LoginActivity which is corelated with LoginViewModel. This activity contains two text boxes, confirm button and textblock for displaying errors. Login is using HttpClient so if any error occurs it will be displayed.

Everything is working correct while debugging.

Problem:
When Linking with 'None' aplpication works correct but it has really big size.
When linking with 'SdkAseembiliesOnly' application run but nothing happens when I click the button.

I guess binding is now working anymore because there is no error message. When button is clicked nothing is being actived.

How can I solve this issue?